# GameObject not moving as intended

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine

I have this code, to move my truck in my Scene in Unity :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TruckMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
Coroutine TruckC;
bool forward = false;
Rigidbody2D truck;
bool collisionTruck = false;

void Start()
{
    truck = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    TruckC = StartCoroutine(Truck());
}

void OnDestroy()
{
    StopCoroutine(TruckC);
}




IEnumerator Truck()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(forward)
        {
            truck.velocity = Vector3.right;
        }
        else
        {
            truck.velocity = Vector3.left;
        }
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => collisionTruck != true);
        forward = !forward;
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag.Equals("Bound"))
    {
        collisionTruck = true;
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag.Equals("Bound"))
    {
        collisionTruck = false;
    }
}
}
```

What I want is it goes from one point to another point and then return.

[image]

My scene is quite weird, so I draw a horrible picture like this.

Also, picture from the scene :

[image]

The problem is the truck is not moving and it's vibrating.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Have you made sure the floor isn't tagged with "Bound"?

Comment: Also, not saying it will solve your problem but you shouldn't be using a Vector3 for the velocity since it's a 2D physics objects. You should be using a Vector2.

Comment: You might also have some logic issues: The coroutine will not continue, and thus change direction, until `collisionTruck` is false, which it will become after it changes direction - so it can never achieve this.

Comment: Oh nvm, `collisionTruck` is initialized as false, so every iteration of the coroutine loop it will change direction and never collide with anything. Thus the vibration.

Comment: @TimHunter `Vector3s can be implicitly converted to Vector2 (z is discarded).` but yes you could consider using `Vector2.right` right away

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem was in my logic .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you even using a Coroutine for that?

You could actually simply do it straight forward in a simple method without having to deal with any flags or waiting like this:

```
public class TruckMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool forward = false;
    private Rigidbody2D truck;

    private void Awake()
    {
        truck = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        // Start moving at the beginning
        ChangeDirection();
    }

    private void ChangeDirection()
    {
        forward = !forward;

        truck.velocity = forward ? Vector2.right : Vector2.left;      
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag.Equals("Bound"))
        {
            ChangeDirection();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @derHugo. Later I used used something like this, inside `LateUpdate()` & `OnCollisionEnter2D()` & using a `Coroutine`. I will post that as answer too.

Answer (score 3):

I think your issue will be solved if you initialize `collisionTruck` as true:

```
bool collisionTruck = true;
```

Right now you have it initialized as `false` and every time it is `false` it will change direction:

```
yield return new WaitUntil(() => collisionTruck != true);
forward = !forward;
```

---

Personally I'd change the variable name to `shouldChangeDirection`, leaving your code looking something like this:

```
/* More stuff */

bool shouldChangeDirection = false;

/* More stuff*/

IEnumerator Truck()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if (forward)
        {
            truck.velocity = Vector3.right;
        }
        else
        {
            truck.velocity = Vector3.left;
        }
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => shouldChangeDirection);
        forward = !forward;
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag.Equals("Bound"))
    {
        shouldChangeDirection = true;
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag.Equals("Bound"))
    {
        shouldChangeDirection = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't need the `OnCollisionExit2D` but should reset the flag right after changing the direction instead.

Comment: @Fredrik Schon thanks a lot... I also have a found a way out, that resembles like the above . I will post that as an answer. Later.

Comment: Agreed @derHugo, I inteded to only fix the issue, not suggest an improved solution.